# Symfony forms: how to include in the Doctrine entity form a form for a Doctrine embeddable used by the entity itself

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, value-objects

I have a Doctrine `Entity` that uses a [Doctrine `embeddable`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html).

I want to create a form to edit the `Entity` and the `Embeddable`.

My `Entity`:

```
/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entities")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Entity\MyEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class MyEntity
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var MyEmbeddableInfo
     *
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable")
     */
    private $myInfo;

    ...
```

My `Embeddable`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class MyInfoEmbeddable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="info1", type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"setUp"})
     */
    private $info1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="info2", type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"setUp"})
     */
    private $info2;

    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="info3", type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"setUp"})
     */
    private $info3;

    ...
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I found this [question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228392/doctrine-embeddables-not-working-with-symfony-forms) and it seems the user had my same problem, but the difference is that I never get that `Warning` as I simply don't understand the basic procedure to create a form for the embeddable object.

I make two tests: one passing directly the embeddable object to the `MyEntityType` form builder and one creating a `MyInfoType()` form type.

**TEST 1: PASS DIRECTLY THE EMBEDDABLE OBJECT**

This is the code of my `MyEntityType`class:

```
class MyEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('myInfo', 'entity', ['class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable'])
            ...
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'MyEntity';
    }
}
```

This solutions throws a `RuntimeException`:

> Class `\AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable` seems not to be
>   a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?

**TEST 2: PASSING THE `MyInfoType` OBJECT**

The second test I make is using a form type (as suggested in the [linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24231517/1399706)):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('myInfo', new MyInfoType())
            ...
    }
```

And this is the code of `MyInfoType`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('infoField1', 'text', ['required' => false])
        ->add('infoField2', 'text', ['required' => false])
        ->add('infoField3', 'choice', [
                'choices'   => [
                    '' => '',
                    'choice1' => 'Choice 1',
                    'choice2' => 'Choice 2',
                    'choice3' => 'Choice 3'
                ],
                'required' => false
            ]
        );
}
```

This, instead, returns a `Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchIndexException`:

> Cannot read index `infoField1` from object of type
>   `AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable` because it doesn't
>   implement `\ArrayAccess`.

So, this solution doesn't work, too.

My goal is to create a form for `MyEntity` and in this form create also the fields to update `MyInfoEmbeddable`.

Which is the correct procedure to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this in your main form:

```
$builder->add('myInfo', new MyInfoType(), 
['data_class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable'])
```

You can add this in your MyInfoType form (which, I believe, linked with embeddable entity):

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
   $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable',
   ]);
}
```

And then simple invoke embeddable form type in your main form like this:

```
$builder->add('myInfo', new MyInfoType())
```

Comment: `$builder->add($builder->create('myInfo', MyInfoType::class));`

Answer (score 2):

After some other searches with different `keywords` I came up with [this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27157736/1399706) that helped me to solve problem.

I were really near to the solution. I simply omitted a required parameter to make the form be built.

The solution is to pass the `data_class` parameter to the `add()` method of the `FormBuilder`:

```
...
$builder
    ->add('myInfo', new MyInfoType(), ['data_class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\Embeddable\MyInfoEmbeddable'])
...
```

Comment: I know, this is a quastion of taste, but I suggest to move 'data_class' attribute from the field invoking in your main form to configureOptions method of your embeddable form.

Comment: Can you write an answer to clarify what do you mean?